# Why does Popover can't work when append data to body table

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-popover

I use popover of the bootstrap and then the problem. when I write javascript for append data add to the table .
The data it can not be called a popover ,
but the first Table written, it can be called popover .
This a function code add table.

```
function myFunction() {
    var addTable = "<tr>" +
        "<td><a style='cursor:pointer' data-toggle='popover' title='Vat Detail' data-html='true' " +
        "data-content='Vat <input type=\"text\" id=\"txtVat[]\" name=\"txtVat[]\" size=\"8\"> </br> " +
        "Invoice <input type=\"text\" id=\"txtVatInvoice[]\" name=\"txtVatInvoice[]\" size=\"8\"> </br> " +
        "DATE <input type=\"text\" id=\"txtVatDate[]\" name=\"txtVatDate[]\" size=\"8\"></br> '>" +
        "VAT </a> </td>" +
        "</tr>";
    $("#myTable tbody").append(addTable);
};
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as php?

Comment: This looks as a javascript problem, not a php problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger the popover using Javascript, look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

This could get the job done:

```
$(function () {
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

Comment: i try this work in HTML code but not work in table from append function

Comment: that work i write $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover() after append row for binding function popover :)